# WOE logistic regression model with 61 variables, will it cause overfitting?

Tags: r, logistic

I've been working a WOE logistic regression model and the data I have is 2878 observations with 814 variables. I used the elastic net to create a penalized regression model so the overall variables have shrinked to 135 as the following code shows.

```
set.seed(123)
list.of.fits <- list()
for (i in 0:10) {

  fit.name <- paste0("alpha", i/10)
  list.of.fits[[fit.name]] <-
    cv.glmnet(x.train, y.train, type.measure="mse", alpha=i/10, 
              family="binomial")
}

## Now we see which alpha (0, 0.1, ... , 0.9, 1) does the best job
## predicting the values in the Testing dataset.
results <- data.frame()
for (i in 0:10) {
  fit.name <- paste0("alpha", i/10)
  
  ## Use each model to predict 'y' given the Testing dataset
  predicted <- 
    predict(list.of.fits[[fit.name]], 
            s=list.of.fits[[fit.name]]$lambda.1se, newx=x.test)
  
  ## Calculate the Mean Squared Error...
  mse <- mean((as.numeric(y.test) - predicted)^2)
  
  ## Store the results
  temp <- data.frame(alpha=i/10, mse=mse, fit.name=fit.name)
  results <- rbind(results, temp)
}

## View the results
results

# > results
# alpha      mse fit.name
# 1    0.0 4.695402   alpha0
# 2    0.1 4.832684 alpha0.1
# 3    0.2 4.141357 alpha0.2
# 4    0.3 4.613409 alpha0.3
# 5    0.4 4.712044 alpha0.4
# 6    0.5 4.588790 alpha0.5
# 7    0.6 4.452613 alpha0.6
# 8    0.7 4.489673 alpha0.7
# 9    0.8 4.344234 alpha0.8
# 10   0.9 4.371251 alpha0.9
# 11   1.0 4.765942   alpha1

# alpha0.2 is the best
```

I used the variables that has coefficients over 0 in the elastic net model into the logistic regression. In total, the variables have been reduced to 135.

Below I used the formula from the elastic net.

```
vars<-rownames(coef(fits))[coef(fits)[,1]>0 & rownames(coef(fits))!="(Intercept)"]

formula = as.formula( paste( 'Y ~', paste( vars , collapse = '+') ) )

m = glm(formula, data_woe, family = 'binomial')
summary(m)
```

Then I used `step` function to select a formula based on AIC.

```
m_step = step(m, direction="both", trace=FALSE)
m = eval(m_step$call)

> summary(m)

Call:
glm(formula = Y ~ income_direct_deposit_woe + amount_desired_woe + 
    residence_length_months_woe + Bankaccountlengthmonths_woe + 
    Salary_woe + ID_FraudRiskScore_woe + NumberofMerchantsAllTime_woe + 
    FPDForABA_woe + FPDForABACount_woe + TotalNumberofLoansDelinquentLastYear_woe + 
    OLNumberofApplications30_woe + OLNumberofMerchants_woe + 
    DistancebetweenHomeZipandIPAddress_woe + ACA_ACH_SATISFACTORY_24M_woe + 
    ACA_ACH_SATISFACTORY_EVER_woe + ACA_TTL_6M_BI_Bad_woe + ACA_TTL_6M_BI_GoodAmt_woe + 
    ACA_OLNumberofApplicationsAllTime_woe + ACA_OLNumberofMerchants_woe + 
    ACA_SFNumberofApplications30_woe + ACA_NumberofMerchantsAllTime_woe + 
    ACA_LL_PD_MERCHANT_6M_woe + ACA_LL_PD_OPEN_6M_woe + ACA_LL_AVG_BAL_woe + 
    TCA_AU21S_woe + TCA_G106S_woe + TCA_BC21S_woe + TCA_OF101S_woe + 
    TCA_OF21S_woe + TCA_FI02S_woe + TCA_FI101S_woe + TCA_FI21S_woe + 
    TCA_FI34S_woe + TCA_G105S_woe + TCA_G416S_woe + TCA_G960S_woe + 
    TCA_G990S_woe + TCA_IN101S_woe + TCA_G208S_woe + TCA_RT09S_woe + 
    TCA_RT34S_woe + TCA_ST02S_woe + TCA_AT09S_woe + TCA_AT104S_woe + 
    TCA_AT57S_woe + TCA_CO04S_woe + TCA_G001B_woe + TCA_G001S_woe + 
    TCA_G051S_woe + TCA_G057S_woe + TCA_G220B_woe + TCA_G235S_woe + 
    TCA_G250C_woe + TCA_G251A_woe + TCA_JT80S_woe + TCA_AUT204_woe + 
    TCA_BKC320_woe + TCA_STD205_woe + TCA_TRV10_woe + EmployerDomainMatch_LastDate_Diff_woe, 
    family = "binomial", data = data_woe)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.49187  -0.49696  -0.23686  -0.08489   3.12302  

Coefficients:
                                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                               -1.75521    0.08546 -20.537  < 2e-16 ***
income_direct_deposit_woe                  1.30794    0.38016   3.441 0.000581 ***
amount_desired_woe                         1.10060    0.24396   4.511 6.44e-06 ***
residence_length_months_woe                1.26075    0.49739   2.535 0.011253 *  
Bankaccountlengthmonths_woe                0.43988    0.18436   2.386 0.017032 *  
Salary_woe                                 0.97032    0.29927   3.242 0.001186 ** 
ID_FraudRiskScore_woe                      0.62794    0.37832   1.660 0.096955 .  
NumberofMerchantsAllTime_woe              -1.48562    0.90830  -1.636 0.101922    
FPDForABA_woe                              0.83443    0.25862   3.226 0.001253 ** 
FPDForABACount_woe                         0.59745    0.39034   1.531 0.125870    
TotalNumberofLoansDelinquentLastYear_woe   0.77682    0.46206   1.681 0.092717 .  
OLNumberofApplications30_woe               1.12550    0.49015   2.296 0.021663 *  
OLNumberofMerchants_woe                   19.33101    9.10940   2.122 0.033830 *  
DistancebetweenHomeZipandIPAddress_woe     0.84206    0.33543   2.510 0.012061 *  
ACA_ACH_SATISFACTORY_24M_woe               0.83459    0.40152   2.079 0.037656 *  
ACA_ACH_SATISFACTORY_EVER_woe              1.44247    0.52563   2.744 0.006065 ** 
ACA_TTL_6M_BI_Bad_woe                      0.87567    0.56228   1.557 0.119385    
ACA_TTL_6M_BI_GoodAmt_woe                  0.72602    0.40688   1.784 0.074368 .  
ACA_OLNumberofApplicationsAllTime_woe      1.17492    0.31530   3.726 0.000194 ***
ACA_OLNumberofMerchants_woe              -18.80171    9.01043  -2.087 0.036919 *  
ACA_SFNumberofApplications30_woe           0.62559    0.31808   1.967 0.049213 *  
ACA_NumberofMerchantsAllTime_woe           2.29167    1.01566   2.256 0.024049 *  
ACA_LL_PD_MERCHANT_6M_woe                  0.72708    0.33732   2.155 0.031124 *  
ACA_LL_PD_OPEN_6M_woe                      1.13246    0.39592   2.860 0.004232 ** 
ACA_LL_AVG_BAL_woe                         1.16034    0.28847   4.022 5.76e-05 ***
TCA_AU21S_woe                              1.61505    0.44720   3.612 0.000304 ***
TCA_G106S_woe                              0.92966    0.32846   2.830 0.004650 ** 
TCA_BC21S_woe                              0.78888    0.38461   2.051 0.040256 *  
TCA_OF101S_woe                             1.28261    0.65111   1.970 0.048854 *  
TCA_OF21S_woe                              1.25526    0.48349   2.596 0.009425 ** 
TCA_FI02S_woe                              1.16132    0.65029   1.786 0.074124 .  
TCA_FI101S_woe                             1.20234    0.45759   2.628 0.008600 ** 
TCA_FI21S_woe                              0.78050    0.48002   1.626 0.103957    
TCA_FI34S_woe                              1.25059    0.35411   3.532 0.000413 ***
TCA_G105S_woe                              1.23387    0.40442   3.051 0.002281 ** 
TCA_G416S_woe                              0.76547    0.32355   2.366 0.017990 *  
TCA_G960S_woe                              0.67281    0.38481   1.748 0.080391 .  
TCA_G990S_woe                              0.95242    0.46115   2.065 0.038893 *  
TCA_IN101S_woe                             1.06988    0.49966   2.141 0.032256 *  
TCA_G208S_woe                              0.76084    0.30912   2.461 0.013842 *  
TCA_RT09S_woe                              1.52938    0.49585   3.084 0.002040 ** 
TCA_RT34S_woe                              0.57449    0.30720   1.870 0.061471 .  
TCA_ST02S_woe                              1.13020    0.29330   3.853 0.000116 ***
TCA_AT09S_woe                              1.27767    0.38159   3.348 0.000813 ***
TCA_AT104S_woe                             0.77484    0.33741   2.296 0.021650 *  
TCA_AT57S_woe                              0.57003    0.31283   1.822 0.068433 .  
TCA_CO04S_woe                              1.19303    0.34851   3.423 0.000619 ***
TCA_G001B_woe                              0.60918    0.39847   1.529 0.126315    
TCA_G001S_woe                              1.24549    0.49753   2.503 0.012303 *  
TCA_G051S_woe                              0.83856    0.27027   3.103 0.001918 ** 
TCA_G057S_woe                              0.69330    0.47602   1.456 0.145267    
TCA_G220B_woe                              1.11414    0.60896   1.830 0.067310 .  
TCA_G235S_woe                              1.41240    0.66936   2.110 0.034851 *  
TCA_G250C_woe                              0.68420    0.45527   1.503 0.132882    
TCA_G251A_woe                              1.15398    0.49315   2.340 0.019282 *  
TCA_JT80S_woe                              0.95442    0.63619   1.500 0.133560    
TCA_AUT204_woe                             0.79848    0.42594   1.875 0.060840 .  
TCA_BKC320_woe                             0.83079    0.31931   2.602 0.009273 ** 
TCA_STD205_woe                             0.77907    0.32006   2.434 0.014929 *  
TCA_TRV10_woe                              0.72360    0.31666   2.285 0.022306 *  
EmployerDomainMatch_LastDate_Diff_woe      0.88215    0.44691   1.974 0.048394 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1834.5  on 2020  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1218.4  on 1960  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1340.4

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

The model I got right now has AUC 0.79 and KS 0.45.

[image]

But it still has 61 variables in the formula. Is it too much and likely to be overfitting? What should I do to select fewer variables without sacrificing too much in prediction?

Thanks,

Comment: (1) can you tell us what WOE means? (2) Why are you following the elasticnet step with an additional AIC-based stepwise procedure?  If your hyperparameter tuning is working correctly (i.e. selecting alpha (ridge vs lasso) and lambda (penalty) parameters via appropriate cross-validation), then you should already be getting close to the  optimal prediction ...

Comment: @BenBolker WOE means weight of evidence. I utilized ```woebin {scorecard}``` to generate the logistic regression model.

Comment: @BenBolker it's a fancy way to bin a predictor variable into levels, taking into account its (univariate) relationship with the response. It's one of those 80-year-old techniques that somehow survives to the present day